# How to validate if a collection contains all unique objects

Tags: c#, collections

I have a C# collection of objects that do not implement IEquatable or IComparable. I want to check if the collection contains duplicate objects. I.e. I want to know if Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) is false for any x and y in my list.

How would I do that efficiently?

It would be nice with both a C# and a LINQ method.

Comment: LINQ is a part of C# you know ;)

Comment: Ok, a pure non-LINQ .NET solution and a LINQ solution then :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-LINQ, when your collection implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`:

```
bool allItemsUnique =
    new HashSet<YourType>(yourCollection).Count == yourCollection.Count;
```

Non-LINQ, when your collection doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`. (This version has slightly better theoretical performance than the first because it will break out early as soon as a duplicate is found.)

```
bool allItemsUnique = true;

var tempSet = new HashSet<YourType>();
foreach (YourType obj in yourCollection)
{
    if (!tempSet.Add(obj))
    {
        allItemsUnique = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

LINQ. (This version's best case performance -- when your collection implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` -- will be roughly the same as the first non-LINQ solution. If your collection doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` then the LINQ version will be less efficient.)

```
bool allItemsUnique =
    yourCollection.Distinct().Count() == yourCollection.Count();
```

Comment: The LINQ expression will not work. Distinct wants IComparables.

Comment: The HashSet also expects IComparable, so neither method will work.

Comment: @Holstebroe: They don't require `IComparable`. I've just tested both versions using a plain `object` collection and they both worked fine.

Comment: My mistake, my list was the result of a LINQ expression with an orderby. After removing the orderby it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use

```
collection.GroupBy(x=>x).Any(x=>x.Count() != 1)
```

Profit is: iterating through collection would stop as soon, as first duplicate object would be found.

Comment: GroupBy expects IComparable which my objects don't implement.